# touch event listerner is not working inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have aded a gesture to my html site using this code:

```
var touchsurface = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0],
        startX,
        startY,
        dist,
        threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
        allowedTime = 2000, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
        elapsedTime,
        startTime;

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    dist = 0;
    startX = touchobj.pageX;
    startY = touchobj.pageY;
    startTime = new Date().getTime(); // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
    e.preventDefault();

}, false);

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
}, false);

touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){

    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
    dist = touchobj.pageX - startX; // get total dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
    // check that elapsed time is within specified, horizontal dist traveled >= threshold, and vertical dist traveled <= 100
    if(elapsedTime <= allowedTime && Math.abs(dist) >= threshold && Math.abs(touchobj.pageY - startY) <= 100){
        load(1);
    }

}, false);
```

my page also contains an iframe object and the listener doesn't react to touches inside the iframe.
I want it to work either on both inside and outside the iframe or only inside the iframe.

Comment: The iframe contains another document, you've to attach the listeners to the document in the iframe.

Comment: how can i do that? i tried attaching it to the iframe object which didn't work. How can i access the document inside?

Comment: If the iframe is loaded from a third-party domain, then you can't achieve what you want (except with a browser extension). If you can control the document in the iframe, then simply put the code to the file loaded to the iframe.